# Get navigation properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In EF6, this method works to retrieve an entity's navigation properties:

```
private List<PropertyInfo> GetNavigationProperties<T>(DbContext context) where T : class
{
    var entityType = typeof(T);
    var elementType = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.ElementType;
    return elementType.NavigationProperties.Select(property => entityType.GetProperty(property.Name)).ToList();
}
```

`IObjectContextAdapter` however does not exist in EF Core. Where should I be looking to get the list of navigation properties of an entity?

Answer (score 11):

Fortunately, access to the model data has become a lot easier in Entity Framework core. This is a way to list entity type names and their navigation property infos:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
...

var modelData = db.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.ClrType.Name,
        NavigationProperties = t.GetNavigations().Select(x => x.PropertyInfo)
    });
```

... where `db` is a context instance.

You would probably like to use the overload `GetEntityTypes(typeof(T))`.

Comment: Or more precisely, `FindEntityType(typeof(T))`. HNY!

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that the EF Core team has said that `FindEntityType(Type)` is not recommended to be used directly in your code because it could change. [Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.model.findentitytype?view=efcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

**EF core 6+**

This works for me:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Fare>().Navigation(f => f.Extras).AutoInclude();
}
```

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations